# Prolog geometric triangle rules

Tags: prolog

Any examples on how to create rules in prolog for equilateral and isosceles triangle in 2d point?

Start with these:

```
equilateral(point2d(x,y), point2d(x,y), point2d(x,y))
isosceles(point2d(x,y), point2d(x,y), point2d(x,y))
```

Comment: Based on your current attempt, I think it might be better to first solve the basics: start with simple predicates like `member/2`, `append/3`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To check if the triangle is equilateral, it's quite simple. To check if it is isosceles, it's a little less trivial. Here my solution:

```
seg_length(X1,Y1,X2,Y2,D):-
    D is sqrt(((X2-X1)**2)+((Y2-Y1)**2)).

equilateral(point2d(X1,Y1), point2d(X2,Y2), point2d(X3,Y3)):-
    seg_length(X1,Y1,X2,Y2,D),
    seg_length(X2,Y2,X3,Y3,D),
    seg_length(X3,Y3,X1,Y1,D).

isosceles(point2d(X1,Y1), point2d(X2,Y2), point2d(X3,Y3)):-
    seg_length(X1,Y1,X2,Y2,D1),
    seg_length(X2,Y2,X3,Y3,D2),
    seg_length(X3,Y3,X1,Y1,D3),
    L = [D1,D2,D3],
    sort(L,LS),
    length(L,LenL),
    length(LS,LenLS),
    LenL \== LenLS.
```

To check if at least two sides are equal, i use `sort/2` which removes duplicates from the list. If the two lists have the same lenght, it means that all three sides are different and so the triangle is not isosceles.

Comment: Another way to check for two identical elements in the list would be something like `select(D,L,L0), select(D,L0,_)` ("take D from L, and then take D again from what's left").